# Column Major Order for OpenGL

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication

I'm writing math classes for use with opengl graphics, which uses column major matrix ordering.  This is homework.

For mat3 (my matrix 3x3 class), along with other matrix classes, I've come up with using a union notation to describe the matrix data.  Now I'm worried that my ordering is wrong (e.g. row major rather than column major).

```
#define real float
union
{
    real _data[9];
    struct
    { 
        real _11; real _12; real _13;
        real _21; real _22; real _23;
        real _31; real _32; real _33;
    };
    struct
    { 
        real _a; real _b; real _c;
        real _d; real _e; real _f;
        real _g; real _h; real _i;
    };

};
```

Should I instead be writing that 2nd struct as follows:

```
struct
{ 
    real _a; real _d; real _g;
    real _b; real _e; real _h;
    real _c; real _f; real _i;
};
```

further, should I be writing the first struct as follows:

```
struct
{ 
    real _11; real _21; real _31;
    real _12; real _22; real _32;
    real _13; real _23; real _33;
};
```

Will this affect the order of matrix multiplication, or other math operations (determinant, inverse, transpose...)?  E.g.  Currently, my mat3 multiply function looks like this:

```
mat3 operator * ( const mat3 & l, const mat3 & r )
{
    // matrix matrix multiply
    return mat3(
        ( (l._11 * r._11) + (l._12 * r._21) + (l._13 * r._31) ), 
        ( (l._11 * r._12) + (l._12 * r._22) + (l._13 * r._32) ), 
        ( (l._11 * r._13) + (l._12 * r._23) + (l._13 * r._33) ),

        ( (l._21 * r._11) + (l._22 * r._21) + (l._23 * r._31) ),
        ( (l._21 * r._12) + (l._22 * r._22) + (l._23 * r._32) ),
        ( (l._21 * r._13) + (l._22 * r._23) + (l._23 * r._33) ),

        ( (l._31 * r._11) + (l._32 * r._21) + (l._33 * r._31) ),
        ( (l._31 * r._12) + (l._32 * r._22) + (l._33 * r._32) ),
        ( (l._31 * r._13) + (l._32 * r._23) + (l._33 * r._33) )
    );
}
```

It's my understanding that this issue confuses a lot of people.  I think the confusion arises after having read text books on the subject, then having to sit down in front of an IDE and write the classes, the two subjects are rarely coverered together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix multiplication, mathematically speaking, works the same way regardless of column/row major ordering. What the column/row major ordering affects is how you *create* those matrices. How you build a rotation matrix, for example.

Furthermore:

> should I be writing the first struct as follows

The whole column/row major thing only matters for *arrays* of values. The column/row major question is about how you store the matrix as an array. If you have an array of 9 values, and the 3x3 matrix is stored in row-major form, then the 2nd column, 1st row's index will be zero-based index 1. In column-major storage, the 2nd column, first row index will be 3.

So look at your union. The point of the union is to access the same float in different ways. The `_21` member is supposed to be 2nd column, first row. If that's the case, then it is your responsibility to make sure that it maps to the right part of the array. If the array is supposed to be column-major, then `_21` should map to the same value as `_data[3]`. If it's row major, it should map to `_data[1]`.